# Probability of a win

Tags: probability

Let's say I have $3$ people who play a game. Player $A,B,C.$
If player $A$ has $0.8$ probability to win the game from player $B$
And if player $B$ has $0.8$ probability to win the game  from player $C$.

What is the probability that player $A$ wins of $C$?

I can't figure this out?

Comment: The phrasing is bad.  What exactly do you mean by "player a has 0.8 probability **to win the game from player b**"  Are you saying that if it were a two player game and a and b were playing against eachother that the probability a wins is 0.8?  What makes you think that this tells you anything about how player c plays against player a?  Maybe player a is an amazing player, player b a mediocre player, and player c a bad player.  Maybe it is rock paper scissors and player c will demolish player a...  not enough information

Comment: Otherwise, if you are saying the probability that player a wins is 0.8 that of player b, and similarly then you have $p(a)=0.8p(b)$ and $p(b)=0.8p(c)$.  let $p(c)$ be shortened as $p$.  You have then $1=0.64p+0.8p+p$ and can solve from there

Comment: I dont get is. How Do you get 1=0,64p+0,8P+p ?

Comment: "having higher chances of beating another player" is **NOT** a transitive relation.  Again, take rock paper scissors as an easy counterexample.  Even though a can beat b regularly and b can beat c regularly, that does **NOT** imply that a will beat c regularly.

Comment: Yes i know that what you saying is true in practice. But lets say my odds are simple facts.

Comment: the probability that player $a$ beats $c$ could be literally anything between zero and one., but that is uninteresting to say because that is true of all probabilities.  There is not enough information.  "Simple facts" or otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes but do you at least agree that it should be bigger then 0,8 cause player a is the best player?

Comment: No I absolutely do not

Comment: You do not? If a is better then b and b is better then c then a must be better then c right?

Comment: Again, there are many things wrong with that logic.  Most importantly, "having a higher probability of beating an opponent" is not a transitive relation meaning that $a\prec b$ and $b\prec c$ does **NOT** imply $a\prec c$.  See for additional example, [James Grime's Nontransitive Dice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWUrwhaqq_c).

Comment: Ok lets leave it at this. I do think a must be better then c. And perhaps i dont explain myself well or/and you dont understan me well. But thx anyway of course.

Comment: I have seen the movie with the dice. But of course that is not what i ment. Lets say we are talking about chess. If play a is better then player b and player b is better then player c. Trust me than a is better then player c. The dice thing is cute but i think a little different story. STill thx.

Comment: How is it any different than your question?  Let player $a$ only get to use the red die.  Let player $b$ only get to use the yellow die.  Let player $c$ only get to use the green die.  For chess too.  Maybe player $a$ plays very aggressively but loses steam and will lose to a player who can delay the game long enough.  Maybe player $b$ is more value minded but can't set up very quick defenses.  Maybe player $c$ is very good at stalling the game and putting up defenses stopping aggressive players but will lose the value game.  Here again you can have $a>b$ and $b>c$ but have $c>a$.

Comment: If you were to specify that this is a "*TRANSITIVE GAME*" (very few actually exist), then yes you could learn that $a$ will beat $c$ with at least probability $0.8$ but you do not have enough information to know anything more specific than that.  It could be any probability from $0.8$ to $1$.  If it is not known to be a transitive game, again it can be any value from $0$ to $1$.  You say "*trust me than a is better then player c.*"  Frankly, I wouldn't trust anyone who can't tell the difference between the words "than" and "then"

Comment: Well ok of course i ment a Transitive game. Please dont get personal withe the comment about "than" and "then". My native language is not english. But you last comment is actually kind of helpfull. Its a transitive game and so it is at least bigger then 0,8 but you cant say the exact odds. Again thank you very much. It was and is , not my intention to get 'overheaded' or get someone 'overheaded'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove this question from the unanswered queue, I will summarize the conversation in the comments above.

Player $a$ having a higher chance to win against player $b$ and player $b$ having a higher chance to win against player $c$ does **NOT** imply that player $a$ will have a higher chance than player $c$.

It is certainly **possible** that $a$ will be able to beat $c$ most of the time  (*e.g. in contests of pure strength or speed*), but without more information **absolutely nothing can be said** about the probability that player $a$ beats player $c$ or vice versa.

[Non-transitive games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_game) are those where $a$ having a higher chance of beating $b$ and $b$ having a higher chance of beating $c$ does not imply that $a$ will have a higher chance to beat $c$.

Among the many examples of games which are nontransitive, some are very obviously nontransitive such as Rock Paper Scissors, Pokemon, Hearthstone,... whereas other games it is not obvious but they still are nontransitive such as chess, baseball, poker.

As a result:  $P(\text{A wins versus C})$ can be anything from $0$ to $1$

---

Only if you specify that the game is [**TRANSITIVE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) can you conclude that $a$ beating $b$ on average and $b$ beating $c$ on average will imply that $a$ will beat $c$ on average.  This still does not imply much about the probabilities involved.  just that $P(\text{A wins versus C})>0.5$

---

in conclusion:  not enough information

Comment: Yes i guess that sums it all up. :-) But of course i did ment a TRANSITIVE game. But i guess then still not much can be said about it. Thank you guys.

Comment: Still is it possible to give me a example for a Transitive game and these odss and some extra information that something can be said about it?

Comment: @thales78 two examples:  both of which are races.  player $a$ runs with a time according to a random variable $A$, $b$ according to random variable $B$, etc, each of which independent of one another... example 1: $A$ is uniformly distributed across the interval $[100,110]$, $B$ uniformly distributed among $[109, 119]$ and $C$ on $[118,128]$.  Here you have $A$ will always beat $C$.  example 2: $A$ is uniformly distributed across $[100,110]$, $B$ is identically $108$, and $C$ is $108.1$ precisely $\frac{4}{5}$ of the time and $99$ the remaining $\frac{1}{5}$ of the time.

Comment: @thales78 in both examples, the game is transitive with respect to these three players (*though it might not necessarily be if we add more players*) and in both examples we have both the probability that $a$ beats $b$ and the probability that $b$ beats $c$ as being $0.8$.  In example 1, player $A$ will beat player $C$ $100\%$ of the time, whereas in example 2 player $A$ will beat player $C$ only approximately $60\%$ of the time.  More carefully crafted examples can show even worse odds for player $A$'s match against player $C$.  This was just what came to my mind first.